# ISO 8601 as input format for Ecto.DateTime.cast()

Tags: timestamp, elixir, ecto

I am processing data from an external API. It returns timestamps as ISO 8601 format, with timezone.

My understanding is that Ecto version 2.1-rc (my version) can handle such timestamps with no issue. However, when I try to perform:

```
created_at = Ecto.DateTime.cast!("2016-10-16T21:21:27-04:00")
```

I receive an error:

```
(Ecto.CastError) cannot cast "2016-10-16T21:21:27-04:00" to datetime
```

Is there an issue with my timestamp?

Answer (score 5):

Your timestamp is valid ISO 8601 but Ecto does not support parsing such datetimes as of `v2.1.0-rc.2`. You can use other libraries like `timex` to parse them, convert to UTC, and then store them in Ecto.

```
iex(1)> "2016-10-16T21:21:27-04:00" |> Timex.parse!("{ISO:Extended}")
#<DateTime(2016-10-16T21:21:27-04:00 Etc/GMT+4)>
iex(2)> "2016-10-16T21:21:27-04:00" |> Timex.parse!("{ISO:Extended}") |> Timex.to_datetime
#<DateTime(2016-10-17T01:21:27Z Etc/UTC)>
```

With Ecto 2.1, you can store this value directly in a `:utc_datetime` field:

```
iex(1)> created_at = "2016-10-16T21:21:27-04:00" |> Timex.parse!("{ISO:Extended}") |> Timex.to_datetime
#<DateTime(2016-10-17T01:21:27Z Etc/UTC)>
iex(2)> Repo.insert!(%Person{created_at: created_at})
12:58:39.959 [debug] QUERY OK db=2.5ms
INSERT INTO "people" ("created_at","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3) RETURNING "id" [{{2016, 10, 17}, {1, 21, 27, 0}}, {{2016, 10, 17}, {7, 28, 39, 945106}}, {{2016, 10, 17}, {7, 28, 39, 948505}}]
%Friends.Person{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "people">, age: nil,
 created_at: #<DateTime(2016-10-17T01:21:27Z Etc/UTC)>, first_name: nil, id: 1,
 inserted_at: ~N[2016-10-17 07:28:39.945106], last_name: nil,
 updated_at: ~N[2016-10-17 07:28:39.948505]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your format is not correct for `Ecto.DateTime.cast`. Please check [it](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.DateTime.html#cast/1) here.

This:

```
created_at = Ecto.DateTime.cast!("2016-10-16T21:21:27")
```

will not throw the error.

Using `-` is forbidden there. Now it's up to you to use other valid ISO-8601 datetime with no `-` sign or just skip it.

Comment: You seemed to have removed the timezone all together, not just the dash. Is there any way to correctly represent the timezone here?